# How to copy my Mountain Lion system to another drive?

Tags: macos, startup, ssd

I'm considering upgrading at long last to Mavericks, but need to feel confident that all my apps & workflows will work properly before committing 100%.  I boot off of an external Thunderbolt SSD normally, so that's where my current boot system is (with all my apps installed, etc.).

I have an internal drive with a secondary simple boot partition, also on Mountain Lion.  I basically use it on those occasions I need to boot from a different partition to do disk diagnostics, test things out in a "sandbox" of sorts, etc.

I'm wondering if I can copy my *current* Mountain Lion system volume - apps and all - to the internal boot partition, and then update THAT drive to Mavericks and run off it for a while until I'm confident that Mavericks is going to work for me.  At that point I would update my SSD and be committed.

Is this viable?  I know that back in the pre-OSX days it was trivial to just copy a system folder and presto - it would boot on a different drive.  But I'm not quite sure this is still the case.

To reiterate, the internal drive I want to copy my system to is already a bootable system partition, so there should be no special blessing or anything required I would think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just imaging my SSD boot drive using Disk Utility and then restoring that image onto my secondary boot drive.  Worked fine and I am now testing out Mavericks without risk to my old system if I decide I need to migrate back.

Comment: That's the same technique I offered using a different tool. Nice point trolling.

Comment: huh?  Don't know what you're talking about.  I didn't really think of this as the same thing as using CCC, it was a lot less trouble than I remember CCC being in the past.  Hell I gave your answer an upvote so I don't see what your problem is.  I was just answering the question with what I actually did, which I thought was the whole point around here...

Answer (score 3):

Cloned drives are generally not a problem. You don't want to do a simple drag/drop. 
[SuperDuper](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper) from ShirtPocket will clone your drive and ensure it's bootable. [CarbonCopyCloner](http://www.bombich.com) will do the same.

There are some more details in [How can I get my laptop's existing system onto a new replacement drive?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/94615/how-can-i-get-my-laptops-existing-system-onto-a-new-replacement-drive/94624#94624)

Comment: Yeah the thing is, I specifically would rather not go through the whole cloning process & restoring a drive to another drive, since this is not a "new" drive, not is it actually going to serve as a "replacement" for my current drive.  Definitely don't want to deal with Time Machine for the same reasons.  Is there any technical reason why drag & drop of my current boot partition's contents will not work, for my purpose of merely evaluating Mavericks for several days before committing my primary drive to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use TimeMachine to save data you need (by default all information include entire system will be saved) and then restore it to new HDD.